# Union: Reading from one data member of a union to write into another

Tags: c++, unions, strict-aliasing

I know that for the code below, "Illegal" below is undefined (while some compilers allow it), because union member "a" is active, and then we read from union member "b". 
The question is, does the code in "AmILegal" fix it, or am I doing something scary and even more obscure? Can I use memcpy to achieve the same effect or is there another undefined behaviour I am invoking there?

EDIT: Maybe the example is not clear enough. All I want to do is activate the other member. 
So I am changing float to int. Although it seems dumb, it is closer to the real case. Read BELOW the code.

(Is it for some reason disallowed to copy one union member into another?)

```
struct Foo
{
    union Bar
    {
        int a[4];
        int b[4];
    };

    void this_is_Illegal()
    {
         a[0]=1;
         a[1]=2;
         a[2]=3;
         a[3]=4;
         std::cout<<b[0]<<b[1]<<b[2]<<b[3];
    }

    void but_is_this_Legal?()
    {
         a[0]=1;
         a[1]=2;
         a[2]=3;
         a[3]=4;

         b[0]=a[0];
         b[1]=a[1];
         b[2]=a[2];
         b[3]=a[3];
         std::cout<<b[0]<<b[1]<<b[2]<<b[3];
    }


    void this_looks_scary_but_is_it?()
    {
         a[0]=1;
         a[1]=2;
         a[2]=3;
         a[3]=4;
         //forget portability for this q, assume sizeof(int)==sizeof(float)
         //maybe memmove works here as well?
         memcpy(b, a, sizeof(int)*4)

         std::cout<<b[0]<<b[1]<<b[2]<<b[3];
    }

};
```

If all of the above does not sound very useful, think that a is in truth an _m128  unioned with a float[4]. The bit representation is exact and correct, always.
At one point in time, you WILL need to actually use it, and you NEED to have it in main memory as an array of floats. 
The "copy instruction" is in truth an _mm_store_ps from the _m128 union member to the float[4] member. Hence the question about the memset - maybe it is the more exact example to what I need...

Comment: Can you post relevant source code?

Comment: "_So I am changing float to int._" I don't understand what you are trying to do; do you want to interpret the bit pattern of a (`int`,`float`) as a (`float`,`int`)? (That is called "type punning".)

Comment: Guys, read the last paragraph below the code. I am explaining exactly the real use case, but since the real code is using VC++ compiler intrinsics et.c. it would be quite unreadable to use here. The use case is returning an __m128's memory location as a float[4] (which is pretty much its definition), while making sure behaviour is defined.

Comment: But there isn't even one `float` declaration in your example!

Comment: There was, but it just confused things by making people try to deduce what I wanted to do with the data in the float, i removed it as the datatypes don't matter for the q: I just want to know what I ask: Is it possible to activate a non-active enum member by writing to it from another enum member. __m128 is the specific case that troubled me, but I would like a generic answer.

Comment: You are so "troubled", you write "enum member". ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second function is perfectly legal - but doesn't do the same thing, since it will perform an int to float conversion rather than leaving the bits unchanged.

To be honest I would just stick with the first one - the behaviour is technically undefined, but I suspect it just does the right thing for you.

The third one switches one form of undefined behaviour for another (once you've written arbitrary bytes into a float, anything could happen). But if you know the bytes really represent a valid floating point value, it's fine.

Comment: The issue with the undefined behaviour is that it may not perform the same way under different compilers or even under different versions of the same compiler, or even under the same version of the same compiler on different platforms.  Therefore, just because it produces the required output, it shouldn't be advocated or encouraged.

Comment: Are you sure about the third one being undefined behaviour? Writing arbitrary bytes onto a float I mean? What I have already does what I want, but I want to make it 1000% portable and valid.

Comment: If you copy the bytes out of a valid float and into another float, then you're ok and the new float has the same value as the old float. If you write arbitrary bytes then all bets are off. (3.9/2-3 in the new standard.)

Answer (score -1):

the this_is_illegal,this_is_legal? pretty much the standard way to use enums ;)

but the memcpy will not work, becayse &a and &b are at the same address because of the enum and memcpy will do nothing

because &a and &b are at the same address you can do some intresting things with the enum - in your case interpret a float as an integer is the built-in feature of your enum, but auto casting can't be triggered, because they are at the same address

you might want to look at **attribute**((packed)) because it helps to declare protocol structs/enums

Comment: "but the memcpy will not work, becayse &a and &b are at the same address because of the enum and memcpy will do nothing" - I know it does not NEED to do anything. All I want to do is make sure the second union member is active so it is "defined" to read from it.

Comment: it's always defined - enum only exists at compile time and it provides typed access to an overlapping memoryspace

Comment: Just because it is the normal way to use unions does not mean that it is well-defined according to the standard.

Comment: @ZoltánNagy Which enum are you talking about?